# Powerful Integral $\int_0^x\frac{t\ln(1-t)}{1+t^2}\ dt$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, polylogarithm

This integral can be found in Cornel's book, ***(Almost) Impossible Integral, Sums and Series*** page $97$ where he showed that

> $$\int_0^x\frac{t\ln(1-t)}{1+t^2}\ dt=\frac14\left(\frac12\ln^2(1+x^2)-2\operatorname{Li}_2(x)+\frac12\operatorname{Li}_2(-x^2)+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)\right)$$

by differentiating $\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)$ then integrating back. How magical is that?

My approach:
\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^x\frac{t\ln(1-t)}{1+t^2}\ dt\overset{IBP}{=}\frac12\ln(1+x^2)\ln(1-x)+\frac12\int_0^x\frac{\ln(1+t^2)}{1-t}\ dt\\
&\overset{1-x=u}{=}\frac12\ln(1+x^2)\ln(1-x)-\frac12\int_{1}^{1-x}\frac{\ln(2+2u+u^2)}{u}\ du\\
&=\frac12\ln(1+x^2)\ln(1-x)-\Re\int_{1}^{1-x}\frac{\ln((1+i)-u)}{u}\ du
\end{align} 
and by using $\displaystyle\int \frac{\ln(a-x)}{x}\ dx=\ln(a)\ln x-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)\ $, we get
\begin{align}
I&=\frac12\ln(1+x^2)\ln(1-x)-\Re\left(\ln(1+i)\ln u-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{u}{1+i}\right)\right)_{u=1}^{u=1-x}\\
&=\frac12\ln(1+x^2)\ln(1-x)-\Re\left(\ln(1+i)\ln(1-x)-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-x}{1+i}\right)+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{1+i}\right)\right)\\
&=\frac12\ln(1+x^2)\ln(1-x)+\frac12\ln2\ln(1-x)+\Re\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-x}{1+i}\right)-\frac{\pi^2}{16}\\
&\boxed{=\frac12\ln\left(2(1+x^2)\right)\ln(1-x)+\Re\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-x}{1+i}\right)-\frac{\pi^2}{16}}
\end{align}
where I used $\ \Re\ln(1+i)=\frac12\ln2\ $ and $\ \Re\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{1+i}\right)=\frac{\pi^2}{16}$.

I tested my solution numerically and all is good but as we can see it does not match Cornel's answer. any idea how to make it match?

Thanks,

Its worth to mention that by comparing the two results proved above, we find the new interesting identity:

> $$\Re\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-x}{1+i}\right)
> =\frac14\left(\frac12\ln^2(1+x^2)-2\ln\left(2(1+x^2)\right)\ln(1-x)-2\operatorname{Li}_2(x)+\frac12\operatorname{Li}_2(-x^2)\\+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)+\frac{\pi^2}{4}\right)$$

Comment: @ automaticallyGenerated yes because they both give the same results. the question is how to make them match.

Comment: no problem.. I always do.

Comment: Are you interested in other approaches? Because I don't have much knowldege about dilogarithms in order to match that. (Not saying that I have one now, but I'm thinking of an approach).//
Btw, maybe  you find this interesting: $$\int_0^x \frac{t\ln(1+t)}{1+t^2}dt=\frac12 \operatorname{Li}_{2}\left(\frac{1-x^2}{2}\right)+\frac12\ln(1-x^2)\ln\left(\frac{1+x^2}{2}\right)-\frac12 \operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac12\right)
-\frac14\left(\frac12\ln^2(1+x^2)-2\operatorname{Li}_2(x)+\frac12\operatorname{Li}_2(-x^2)+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)\right)$$

Comment: @Zacky nice result. did you verify it? I just want to make my result match with Cornels'.

Comment: @AliShather What is the range of $x$ for your formula?// At mine for $x=1$ doesn't seem to work, but it does for $\frac12$ and $\frac13$. Idk what's going on, I guess it works only for $x\in (0,1)$.

Comment: Commenting since it doesn't work. My idea was to consider the following integrals:$$I=\int_0^x \frac{t\ln(1-t)}{1+t^2}dt, \quad J=\int_0^x \frac{t\ln(1+t)}{1+t^2}dt$$
$$I+J=\int_0^x\frac{t\ln(1-t^2)}{1+t^2}dt\overset{t^2=y}=\frac12\int_0^{x^2}\frac{\ln(1-y)}{1+y}dy$$
$$=\frac12 \left(\operatorname{Li}_{2}\left(\frac{1-x^2}{2}\right)+\ln(1-x^2)\ln\left(\frac{1+x^2}{2}\right)- \operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac12\right)\right)$$ 
Similarly for $I-J$, just let $\frac{1-t}{1+t}$ and use partial fractions. 
Then $2I=(I+J)+(I-J)$. From the above the integral result that I mentioned easily follows.

Comment: @Zacky $x$ can be any number. if we use my result or yours for $x=1$, it does not seem to work but its fine if we use Cornels'. now we can see the big difference between these results.

Comment: nice idea Zacky. thats one of my fav techniques.

Comment: @AliShather I just re-verified the formula from above, it works for any numbers too (including $x=1$). I don't know what went wrong the first time, but it works just fine. I don't know how to match it with that, but atleast we can get $3$ representations for it.

Comment: @Zacky thats good . that means no problem with my result as well. maybe manipulating with dilogarithm identities would cancel out that $\ln(1-x)$.just a guess... have not tried yet. .